# Default Implementation of Coq typeclass methods

Tags: haskell, coq, typeclass

Is there a way you can provide default implementations of Coq typeclass methods like you can in Haskell? I saw no mention of this in the Coq typeclass documentation. If there does not exist such a feature, is there a common pattern for emulating this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default implementation can be viewed as a function which constructs the default methods given other provided methods. So you can just define a function.

```
Class C a :=
  { m1 : a
  ; m2 : a
  }.

(* Construct an instance of C from an implementation of only m1. *)
Definition mkC {a} (m1_ : a) := {| m1 := m1_ ; m2 := m1_ |}.

#[global]
Instance C_nat : C nat := mkC 0.
```

Another idea is to break the class into single-method classes. Then you can first define instances for the explicitly implemented methods, and then again use functions to obtain default implementations for other methods. By breaking down the class this way, you don't need to explicitly apply the default function to the provided methods.

```
Class N1 a :=
  n1 : a.

Class N2 a :=
  n2 : a.

(* Default implementation of N2 using N1 *)
Definition defaultN2 {a} {_ : N1 a} : N2 a := n1 (a := a).

#[global]
Instance N1_nat : N1 nat := 0.

#[global]
Instance N2_nat : N2 nat := defaultN2.  (* N1 nat is passed implicitly here *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish that you could do this, but it is not supported.